# Need content to reappear after multiple check boxes are unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple check-boxes that filter content in another div, after checking a checkbox, only the content that pertains to the checkbox is displayed and the rest is hidden, and as you check more boxes, more content is therefore shown.

The problem I am having is that when i uncheck all of the boxes, all of the content disappears, whereas I want all of the content to appear back when i uncheck all of the boxes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function() {
    $('.results > div').hide();
    $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function() {
      $('.results > div.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tags">
  <ul class="list-unstyled filterSection">
    <li>
      <label class="filter-check clearfix">
                <input type="checkbox" rel="1" id="1" />
                <label for="1">1</label>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="filter-check clearfix">
                <input type="checkbox" rel="2" id="2" />
                <label for="2">2</label>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="filter-check clearfix">
                <input type="checkbox" rel="3" id="3" />
                <label for="3">3</label>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="filter-check clearfix">
                <input type="checkbox" rel="4" id="4" />
                <label for="4">4</label>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="filter-check clearfix">
                <input type="checkbox" rel="5" id="5" />
                <label for="5">5</label>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="results" id="">
  <div class="1 m-3 border-new border border-dark rounded">
    <a href="">
      <img src="images/1.jpg">
      <div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="1 m-3  border-new border border-dark rounded">
    <a href="">
      <img src="images/1.jpg">
      <div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="2 m-3  border-new border border-dark rounded">
    <a href="">
      <img src="images/2.jpg">
      <div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="2 m-3  border-new border border-dark rounded">
    <a href="">
      <img src="images/2.jpg">
      <div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="3 m-3  border-new border border-dark rounded">
    <a href="">
      <img src="images/3.jpg">
      <div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="5 m-3  border-new border border-dark rounded">
    <a href="">
      <img src="images/5.jpg">
      <div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="1 m-3  border-new border border-dark rounded">
    <a href="">
      <img src="images/1.jpg">
      <div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="4 m-3  border-new border border-dark rounded">
    <a href="">
      <img src="images/4.jpg">
      <div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="1 m-3  border-new border border-dark rounded">
    <a href="">
      <img src="images/1.jpg">
      <div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="3 m-3  border-new border border-dark rounded">
    <a href="">
      <img src="images/3.jpg">
      <div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="4 m-3  border-new border border-dark rounded">
    <a href="">
      <img src="images/4.jpg">
      <div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As a side-note, I'd recommend using [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) instead of CSS classes to assign, refer to and use properties that aren't related to styling. Mixing classes that assign styles with classes that don't is a footgun imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't listen for `click` events on checkboxes; there's a dedicated `change` event for this. If I toggle the checkbox with the keyboard, your `click` event won't fire.

Secondly, it's just a case of listening for how many checked checkboxes were found, then acting accordingly.

```
$('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
    let
    els = $('.results > div').hide(),
    checked = $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function() {
        els.filter('.'+$(this).attr('rel')).show();
    });
    if (!checked.length) els.show(); //<-- none checked? Show all
});
```

Note also that by assigning `els`, we can avoid repeated lookups on the same selector.

Comment: Also I want to ask, why does this script only work in the footer, if I put it in my javascript file, it doesn't work.

Comment: We'd need more info. There's no reason that should be the case if the script is getting called and it's running inside a document-ready callback.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you looking?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        const tags = $('div.tags');
        const checkboxes = tags.find('input:checkbox');
        const results = $('.results');
        const resultsDiv = results.find('div');
        checkboxes.on('change', function () {
            if (checkboxes.get().some(item => item.checked)) {
              resultsDiv.hide();
            } else {
              resultsDiv.show();
            }
            $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () {
                $('.results > div.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tags">
    <ul class="list-unstyled filterSection">
        <li>
            <label class="filter-check clearfix">
                <input type="checkbox" rel="1" id="1" />
                <label for="1">1</label>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="filter-check clearfix">
                <input type="checkbox" rel="2" id="2" />
                <label for="2">2</label>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="filter-check clearfix">
                <input type="checkbox" rel="3" id="3" />
                <label for="3">3</label>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="filter-check clearfix">
                <input type="checkbox" rel="4" id="4" />
                <label for="4">4</label>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="filter-check clearfix">
                <input type="checkbox" rel="5" id="5" />
                <label for="5">5</label>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="results" id="">
    <div class="1 m-3 border-new border border-dark rounded">
        <a href="">
            <img src="images/1.jpg">
            <div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="1 m-3  border-new border border-dark rounded">
        <a href="">
            <img src="images/1.jpg">
            <div>
            </div>
        </a>                            
    </div>
    <div class="2 m-3  border-new border border-dark rounded">
        <a href="">
            <img src="images/2.jpg">
            <div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="2 m-3  border-new border border-dark rounded">
        <a href="">
            <img src="images/2.jpg">
                <div>
                </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="3 m-3  border-new border border-dark rounded">
        <a href="">
            <img src="images/3.jpg">
            <div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="5 m-3  border-new border border-dark rounded">
        <a href="">
            <img src="images/5.jpg">
            <div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="1 m-3  border-new border border-dark rounded">
        <a href="">
            <img src="images/1.jpg">
            <div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="4 m-3  border-new border border-dark rounded">
        <a href="">
            <img src="images/4.jpg">
            <div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="1 m-3  border-new border border-dark rounded">
        <a href="">
            <img src="images/1.jpg">
            <div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="3 m-3  border-new border border-dark rounded">
        <a href="">
            <img src="images/3.jpg">
            <div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="4 m-3  border-new border border-dark rounded">
        <a href="">
            <img src="images/4.jpg">
            <div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```